# WOL not working with two NIC's

Tags: windows-server-2008, wake-on-lan

We have recently moved from a windows 2003 server to an 08 R2. Running the program from the command line says that the magic packet has successfully been sent but it never actually reached the destination computer.

We have two NIC's on the server. If I disable the NIC that isn't (currently) in use, WOL will work fine, but in the future we will need to use both NIC's.

Also, we use MAC Addresses for WOL.

Comment: How about if you just disconnect the second NIC, without disabling?  Also - what method are you using to verify that the magic packet never arrived?

Comment: Can your program be told what interface to send the WOL packet on?

Comment: As for checking how I verify if it arrived or not I have just been turning off one of the systems that I am testing it on and running the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you waking the server, or using the server to wake other devices?

If you're trying to send wakeup frames from the server, it may be sending them out the wrong NIC. Depending on the utility you're using to send the WoL packet, you should be able to specify the subnet where you want it to go.

Alternatively, you can change the NIC binding order, and put the interface you want to send wakeup frames from at the top. Instructions here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd391967%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Comment: I am sending packets from the server, it wouldn't help to specify the subnet because I am using MAC addresses.

Comment: Actually I just had to change the binding order. Thanks for the help!

Comment: The subnet is significant even when you're sending just to MAC addresses, because it uses the subnet to determine which network to send the packets to. If you ever want to send packets to devices on the other NIC's network, you'll need to specify the subnet - but until then, you're golden!